# Simulating hardware key events in chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-nativeclient

I want to simulate a key press from a chrome extension. It needs to be like a real key press: it must prevent the screensaver from popping up.

Javascript is not an option since it can only simulate JS events, not send a real key press event to the OS.

I was thinking of pNaCl, but haven't found any documentation on how to generate keyboard events.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it's not possible now (not 100% sure).  Since Google is expending chrome.input.ime API. It would be possible soon.

See https://docs.google.com/document/d/1pqZO80ZOmgWzuQphf-uq5y967umcy7tqw5ETjuF19TU/edit#